# iText & Arabic pdfs ocasionally missing characters

Tags: java, itext, arabic

I'm trying to produce Arabic pdf documents using iText 4.2.1. The documents are based on templates supplied in Word xml format. I'm just about there but have hit a snag.

The source documents use the *Simplified Arabic* font and display fine, so I have used the same in the PDF. For the most part everything is fine, but occasionally it "drops" a character.

I've traced through the iText source and can see where it converts from the 0x06xx base code through to the 0xFExx presentation code depending on the shaping rules. Once it has translated to the presentation code it then looks up the metrics of each character in turn from the font file, prior to writing into the document output stream. It is here that it is sometimes unable to locate the required *presentation* code in the font, so just omits the character all together.

As an example, character 0x0645 translates to 0xFEE2 using this line from the charMap table

```
    {0x0645, 0xFEE1, 0xFEE2, 0xFEE3, 0xFEE4}, /* MEEM */
```

... and 0xFEE2 is not in the Simplified Arabic font.

Given that the documents display fine in Word using the same font, should iText be reverting to use the base code 0x6xx for presentation? If so, is this resolved in the commercial version of the libraries (for which I'm happy to pay if necessary).

Alternatively, is this an issue with the font which other libraries have to work around

Has anyone else hit this snag or similar and if so, what did you do to resolve it?

Comment: I had similar problem with polish letters - there is article which helped me. I'm afraid it's in polish, but google.translate should be enough to understand the core of this ;)
http://soft-java.net/solutions/iText-poskie-znaki-tworzenie-PDF#pr1
The main thing to do is to change encoding in iText class `com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont` in `createFont` method.

Comment: Thanks rzysia. Using Arial instead of Simplified Arabic and setting the correct encoding worked for me.

Comment: Not only is `4.2.1` a very old version, as Paulo writes, it is even a version that was never released by iText Software but by someone else. iText went from `2.1.7` to `5.0.0`. There was a tag `4.2.0` in the old SVN repository, but that was never used to create a release build. It was only used to sync up with the .NET port. Someone else took that tag, made some changes, and released that as `4.2.1`, but not under their own name, as they should have done.

Answer (score 3):

Arabic has a logical text representation in the 0x6xx range and a visual presentation in two other ranges:
FB50 — FDFF Arabic Presentation Forms-A
FE70 — FEFF Arabic Presentation Forms-B

The presentation ranges must be used as for each character you may have four representation depending on word location: initial, medial, final and isolated. Other ligatures are possible.

Setting aside your usage of a mighty old iText version, if the character is not in the font it can't be represented. Word will use other fonts if the font has a missing character or it may use an alternative character. Try using Arial to make sure that the ligatures are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paulo. I suspect that Word is applying some sort of correction for missing glyphs within the font, perhaps reverting to the 0x6xx representation if it doesn't exist in the Presentation space. However, I took your advice regarding Arial, and that seems to have done the trick. I had previously avoided using Arial for non-Latin text as we had been unable to display anything other than basic Latin characters. I've just realised we were using the wrong encoding! Doh.

Answer (score 2):

We recently encountered the same situation and we are presenting what we did for this issues:

1. In our case - The document was authored in MS Word in Arabic. When you select a single character and Alt+x, in MS Word - you are able to see the Unicode of the character. The unicode lied in Normal Unicode Range (0600—06FF, 255 Characters).
2. When the said document was converted into the PDF - using either 'Save as PDF' in MS Word or using 'Adobe Acrobat Professional', The Normal Arabic Unicode was replaced by Arabic Presentation Form A [611 characters, depending if the character is in isolation or starting or middle or end of word] and B [143 characters] related Glyphs.
3. As per the blog of someone from Adobe - "PDF specifies text content of pages as glyphs not characters" - link: http://blogs.adobe.com/insidepdf/2008/07/text_content_in_pdf_files.html
4. Even though - every where on internet - it is written "it is NOT Recommended not to use the presentation formats" the conversion to PDF - resulted in the change from normal unicode arabic character set to Presentation Form A & B character set.
5. When we extracted the text - using PDFBox - we received characters in the Presentation Form A and B series Unicode. Interestingly - since we can't read arabic - when we copied and pasted the text in google translate - we received the same output, however when we did the difference by computing diff - we received that there is nothing common between the 2 strings. [Till that point of time - we were unaware of normal unicode arabic, presentation form a of arabic - which is also a part of unicode etc]
6. We had the business requirement of extracting the original characterset from PDF. This was challenging - Presentation Form A & B have about 4 forms- for each character [depending upon its location in word].

We actively looked on the internet - if there was any library - which can establish the relationship between the two.

Thankfully - Unicode has Replacement Characterset - which defines how we can move back from Presentation Form A & B character [Character Fall Back Substitutions] -set to Normal Unicode Character-set.

http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/29/supplemental/character_fallback_substitutions.html

Using the above data source - we were able to get define the translation back to normal arabic character set of 591/611 characters in Arabic Presentation Form A unicode set and 139/143 characters in Arabic Presentation Form B unicode character set.

Adobe - also has Adobe Glyph List Specification - [available on github] - which also defines relationship between the Glyphs and their unicode - but is incomplete for arabic as it defines on 257 characters - which also fall mostly in Arabic Presentation Form A series.

Further - in our case-  there were no missing characters. The characters were only translated from our the concerned normal Arabic Unicode to Presentation Forms.

In our original MS Word Document - there were tables - inside which there was contents. In translated arabic - we received FFFD unicode character [questionmark, which indicated that there were some characters which could not get translated when changed in unicode happened.] IF deleted all such FFFD characters - the remaining text - though converted into Presentation form A unicode set - had the same meaning as original one.

We did spend substantial time in resolving this issue of change in unicodes when converted into PDF and hope our experience will be of aid to someone else as well.